# Zend use of element decorators inside a Subform viewScript decorator

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, subform

I need to force the use of a decorator for a specific element, into a viewScript used for a subform.

This is how i've set the decorator for the subform:

```
$subform->setDecorators(array(
'PrepareElements',
array(array('tabs' => 'ViewScript'),
array('viewScript'=>'_subform_tabs.phtml','viewModule'=>'default', 'placement' => 'append')),
));
```

and following the decorator of the field (checkbox):

```
$element->setDecorators(array(
'Errors',
array('ViewScript', array('viewScript'=>'_multicheckboxview.phtml','viewModule'=>'admin')),
));
```

and now the way i show the element into the _subform_tabs.phtml viewScript:

```
echo $this->{$elem->helper}(
$elem->getName(),
$elem->getValue(),
$elem->getAttribs(),
$elem->getMultiOptions());
```

The checkbox element is showed into the subform skipping the viewScript decorator which i've set for the field, mainly because no decorator is specified into the subform script.

How can i resolve that?

Any help is appreciated.